# JavaScript effects are not working on Elementor edit page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I'm developing an elementor widget. The widget font view js is working fine but the elementor edit page js effects are not working. I'm using some hooks to try. Now, What is the perfect way to js loading for elementor edit page.

WP Plugin Link:- https://github.com/Ferdaussk/image-compare.git

Problem Video:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lOy1TEHUszLXEYvdJueZQrOuqsaax-nX/view?usp=sharing

All assets enqueue hooks which I used

```
    public function bwdic_all_assets_for_the_public(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_main_one_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-one.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_mainel_two_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-two.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_mainel_three_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-three.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_mainel_four_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-four.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_mainel_five_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-five.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_the_mainel_six_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-six.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    $all_css_js_file = array(
        'bwdic_compare_main_css' => array('bwdic_path_define'=>BWDIC_ASFSK_ASSETS_PUBLIC_DIR_FILE . '/css/style.css'),
    );
    foreach($all_css_js_file as $handle => $fileinfo){
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $fileinfo['bwdic_path_define'], null, '1.0', 'all');
    }
}
public function bwdic_all_assets_for_elementor_editor_admin(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_admin_the_main_one_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/admin/js/custom-one.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    $all_css_js_file = array(
        'bwdic_compare_admin_icon_css' => array('bwdic_path_admin_define'=>BWDIC_ASFSK_ASSETS_ADMIN_DIR_FILE . '/icon.css'),
    );
    foreach($all_css_js_file as $handle => $fileinfo){
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $fileinfo['bwdic_path_admin_define'], null, '1.0', 'all');
    }
}
public function bwdic_all_assets_for_the_frontens_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bwdic_compare_admin_the_main_one_jsaa', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/public/js/custom-one.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}

public function __construct() {
    // For public assets
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'bwdic_all_assets_for_the_public']);

    // For fontend scripts
    add_action( 'elementor/frontend/init', [ $this, 'bwdic_all_assets_for_the_frontens_scripts' ] );

    // For Elementor Editor
    add_action('elementor/editor/before_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'bwdic_all_assets_for_elementor_editor_admin']);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question with code snippets and a detailed description what exactly you are trying and what exactly makes you problems. This question as it is, cannot be answered. There are no gods on Stackoverflow, just humans.

Answer (score -1):

You should check your console in chrome developer tools.
Sometimes there is bug when elementor editor doesn't apply ur javascript changes in real time. If you check console, you will know what I mean